# Type of property does not match type of accessor (when subclassing)

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, properties

OK I know that this subject has been mentioned many times before on SO, but after checking several such questions, none have talked about the issue I am having with regards to overriding the base class getters/setters in a subclass.

My base class is:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface BaseClass : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) int value;
@end

@implementation BaseClass
@synthesize value;
@end
```

From that I want the subclass to act as a shim and map the "value" from an int to an enum in my child class:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "BaseClass.h"

typedef enum {
    zero = 0,
    one,
    two,
    three,
    four
} NumberEnum;

@interface ChildClass : BaseClass
-(void)setValue:(NumberEnum)newValue;
-(NumberEnum)value;
@end

@implementation ChildClass

-(void)setValue:(NumberEnum)newValue
{
    [super setValue:(int)newValue];
    NSLog(@"Child Setter");
}

-(NumberEnum)value
{
    NSLog(@"Child Getter");
    return (NumberEnum)[super value];
}

@end
```

And I test this code using:

```
ChildClass* fred = [[ChildClass alloc] init];
NumberEnum barney;
fred.value = one;
barney = fred.value;
barney = [fred value];
```

XCode (4.5.2) generates the warning

> Type of property 'value' does not match type of accessor 'value'

On this line **only**:

```
barney = fred.value;
```

When the code is run, I see the log messages for both the Child Setter and Getter.  So what should I be doing to eliminate this warning, and why am I getting it in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The offending line:

```
barney = fred.value;
```

tells the compiler you want to use the property `value`. As your child class doesn't define it, it goes up to the base class. It found `value` with a different type causing the warning.

A solution is to write your property as:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) int value;
```

and the enum as:

```
enum {
    zero = 0,
    one,
    two,
    three,
    four
};
typedef int NumberEnum;
```

This way synthesized property methods and your own implementations are working with the same data type. You can use symbolic values and there is no warning.

I suggest using `NSUInteger` instead, as it is 64-bits friendly.

And of course, much better if you just define the property as `NumberEnum` in the base class.

Comment: Both the fred.value and [fred value] calls pass through the getter defined in the child class.  And my understanding is that the fred.value syntax is really syntactic sugar that does an implicit [fred value], and as such I would expect the warning either on both lines, or neither of the lines.  However I do agree that your solution works!  (Or course the whole reason for having inheritance in the first place is that I have multiple child classes that have some common code which I am pushing into the base class)

Answer (score 1):

Your `@property` says `int` and the compiler is probably messing up with your methods. Try setting the `@property` type to `NumberEnum` and it should work (you will need to move the enum definition to your .h)

Comment: I can't move the enum to the base class as the base class is used as a bass class for more than one child class.

Comment: @PeterM Then you can't change the type of the `property` or its accessors in the subclass.

Comment: Then maybe you have some design issue if your subclasses handle different types for the same properties, even if it's changing an int to an enumerator. Perhaps making a new property in your `ChildClass`, and then overwrite the `value` getter/setter methods there.

Comment: @Ismael The base class contains common code that can be shared between different child classes, and an enum is basically an int with a pre-defined set of permissible values.

Comment: Well, you asked what the warning was about, and as far as the compiler goes, `int` and `NumberEnum` are not the same thing, clearly.

Comment: When you do `barney = fred.value;` it is probably going for the synthesized getter of your `BaseClass`, so it's trying to put an `int` into a `NumberEnum`, which might be a problem if your `int` value is not within the scope of your enum. I hope I was clear

Comment: @Ismael The log messages show that it is going through the overridden getter, and I am explicitly casting from int to enum, so there should be no reason for the warning.  And casting an out of range int to an enum is more an undefined action, not an illegal action - but that is a run time rather than compile time issue..